# Python dict.keys() has the key but acts as it doesn´t have it

Tags: python, dictionary, spyder, xlrd, xlwt

I´m replacing a lot of values in an Excel, so I have a dictionary with hundreds of keys, but when a key has a slash ( / ), it doesn´t enter the if.

As you can see I have tried using doble, //, and adding r before to make it a literal.

When I do is ("stringwith /slash") in dict.keys() I get a True, but when I run the program, they are skipped, as if they don´t exist.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd


dictForReplacement={}


for i in range(0,101):
    x = "Estigfend" + str(i) + str(i)+ " puntos de 100"
    dictForReplacement[x] = str(i)
    x = "Estigfend" + str(i) + str(i)+ " puntos de 100Completada con retraso"
    dictForReplacement[x] = str(i)
    x = "Estigfend" + str(i) + str(i)+ " puntos de 100Presentada de nuevo"
    dictForReplacement[x] = str(i)
    x = "Estigfend" + str(i) + str(i)+ " puntos de 100Borrador"
    dictForReplacement[x] = str(i)    
    x = "Estigfend" + str(i) + str(i)+ " puntos de 100Sin entregar"
    dictForReplacement[x] = str(i)    
    x = "Estigfend" + str(i)+"/100" + str(i)+ " puntos de 100Sin entregar"
    dictForReplacement[x] = str(i)    
    x = "Estigfend" + str(i)+"/100" + str(i)+ " puntos de 100"
    dictForReplacement[x] = str(i)  

dictForReplacement[r"EstigfendSin entregar"] = "NP"



dictForReplacement["EstigfendTarea asignada"] = "TA"


#here is the problem, the number was in case I founded the solution

dictForReplacement[r"Estigfend /100Sin calificación"] = "NP 00"
dictForReplacement[r"Estigfend /100Sin calificación"] = "NC 0"
dictForReplacement["Estigfend //100Sin calificación"] = "NC 1"
dictForReplacement[r'Estigfend //100Sin calificaciónCompletada con retraso'] = "NC 2"
dictForReplacement['Estigfend /100Sin calificaciónCompletada con retraso'] = "NC 3"
dictForReplacement[r"Estigfend /100Sin calificaciónCompletada con retraso"] = "NC 4"
dictForReplacement[r"Estigfend /100Sin calificaciónBorrador"] = "NC 5"



dictForReplacement["Estigfend /100Sin calificación"] = "NP" 

###################################################
#heres the if


ExcelNewName = "AAA"
########################################## Name of Excel to be modified
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Intento Calificaciones clear.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Hoja1')

#write the data into new Excel file:
new_workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
new_sheet = new_workbook.add_sheet('Hoja1')


for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    
    data = [sheet.cell_value(i, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]

    for index, value in enumerate(data):

        if value in dictForReplacement.keys():
            new_sheet.write(i, index, str(dictForReplacement.get(value)))
        else:
            new_sheet.write(i, index, value)
            
            
new_workbook.save(ExcelNewName+'.xls')
```

This is my code without Ktinder, since its a GUI I know it isnt needed here

So now you can also run it.

edit4: the next 3 lines wrong
Idk how to add a excel file here, the biggest problem is  the strings with /, so just create a page and have a cell be :
Estigfend /100Sin calificación

edit2: someone said there must likely be that excel is adding other things, I´ll look into it

edit3:
[image: add a print to see value and error, same string]

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: To simplify your string creation, consider using f-strings. For example, your first statement would become: `x = f"Estigfend{i}{i} puntos de 100"` This might make identifying errors in your variable names easier to identify

Comment: To make debugging the problem easier, try printing `value` at each instance of the loop. Perhaps your excel document has character's you're not accounting for, such as `'\n'`, or additional spaces that are causing the `if` statement to fail. On it's own, a key with a `/` is not meaningfully different than one without, so I suspect there is something else going on here.

Comment: @zvone, I think now is reproduceable, I joined the code, the only thing beside this is to have an excel and put that name or change the var

Comment: Thanks for the advice @CollinHeist, will look into it, both comments

Comment: Maybe it is reproducible, but is definitely is not minimal. You are saying that `dict[key]` and `key in dict` or `dict.keys()` are inconsistent. It should be possible to show that in 3 lines, if you can really reproduce it.

Comment: @zvone sorry, I dont fully understad how to show the problem in 3 lines, can you explain me how to do it, and I´ll do it. Sorry to bother you, this all new. Is just that since my problem is with my dict I think I have to show how is made, and to show where it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was invisible characters!

My mistake, dict.keys() works fine obviously, but when printing the values that didn´t had a key (when I knew I had all possible options as keys), I saw they looked just like my keys, but they aren´t the same due to invisible characters!!!

I changed part of the code to get a list of all the bad values, using the else, then in a for of this list applied print(repr(value)) to see the invisible characters

and saw this:

[image: Result of print(repr(value)) using bad values]

So my Excel is weird, as previously said by @CollinHeist in comments, this did it

```
dictForReplacement[r"Estigfend\xa0/100Sin calificación"] = "NP"
```

Thanks commenters

Comment: Good job! The main reason you should always try to minimize the problem is that once you do that and try find the exact thing which causes the problem, you usually end up having the solution clearly in front of you, as it happened here ;)